# How to make my HashMap work as expected?

Tags: java, hashmap

Suppose one has a simple class:

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {

    public int compareTo(Point p) {
        if ((p.x == this.x) && (p.y == this.y)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (((p.x == this.x) && (p.y > this.y)) || p.x > this.x) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

And a `HashMap` from `Point` to something, let's say `Cell`:
`cellMap = new HashMap<Point, Cell>();`
Then one fills in `cellMap` as follows:

```
for (int x = -width; x <= width; x++) {
    for (int y = -height; y <= height; y++) {
        final Point pt = new Point(x,y);
        cellMap.put(pt, new Cell());
        }
    }
}
```

And then one does something like (trivial) this:

```
for (Point pt : cellMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(cellMap.containsKey(pt));
            Point p = new Point(pt.getX(), pt.getY());
            System.out.println(cellMap.containsKey(p));
}
```

And gets `true` and `false` in, respectively, first and second cases. What is going on? Is this map comparing hashes instead of values? How to make the example return true in both cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using `HashMap`, not `TreeMap`, you need to override `hashCode` and `equals`, not `compareTo`, in your `Point` class:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31*x + y;
}
@Override
public bool equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof Point)) return false;
    Point p = (Point)other;
    return x == p.x && y == p.y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Another question: if I override `hashCode` to return the same hash for points with equal coordinates, I won't have ability (let's suppose I DO need it) to distinguish `p1 = new Point(0, 0)` and `p2 = new Point(0, 0)`?

Comment: @cdshines You can always distinguish between two instances representing equivalent objects using reference equality `==`. You can even use them in an `InstanceHashMap` (which is not a proper hash map, because it does not follow the same contract).